# Let $x$ be a real number such that $|x|<1.$ Which of the following is false?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be a real number such that $|x|<1.$ Which of the following is false?

1. If $x\in \mathbb Q$, then $\sum_{m\ge 0}x^m \in \mathbb Q$
2. If $\sum_{m\ge 0}x^m \in \mathbb Q$ then $x\in \mathbb Q$
3. If $x\notin \mathbb Q$ then $\sum_{m\ge 0}mx^{m-1} \notin \mathbb Q$
4. $\sum_{m\ge 0}x^m/m $ converges in $\mathbb R$

My attempt:-

$\sum_{m\ge 0}x^m =\frac{1}{1-x}$, If $x\in \mathbb Q$ then $\frac{1}{1-x}\in \mathbb Q$

Similarly, If $\frac{1}{1-x} \in \mathbb Q\implies 1-x \in \mathbb Q \implies$ $x\in \mathbb Q$

Also we know that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{m\ge 0}mx^{m-1} \in \mathbb Q$, If $x=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$
 So, (3) is the False statement. But In answer key it was given that (2) is the answer. I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you have done is correct except that you cannot take $x=1+\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ since $|x|<1$. Take $x=1-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ instead.

Comment: Option (4) $\sum_{m\ge 0}x^m/m=-\log(1-x)$. right. I know it is converges in $|x|<1$. But in the option they have written $x\in \mathbb R$ But in the question. They have written correctly.

Comment: @Mathgeek The series in 4) converges iff $-1\leq x <1$.

Comment: So, (4) is also false. right?

Comment: @Mathgeek Yes, it is false.